# How to make this kind of custom algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am enhancing my Java skills for my own personal purpose,

And I am wondering, how to make this algorithm in Java :

```
* 2 3 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* * * 4 5
* * * * 5
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * 5
* * * 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* 2 3 4 5
```

---

**So far from now I managed to do this** :

```
*
**
***
****
*****

for (int i = 1; i <=5 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <=i ; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

---

And I wanted to do something harder.

Comment: Solution: keep working at it.  That's the best way to learn how to program.  Practice.

Comment: Hint: one way to do this is to change the inner loop to always run to 5, and use an `if` inside. Another option is to use a second, separate inner loop for the numbers.

Comment: I prefer the second inner loop, @Hulk. It will be easier to read even when calculating the loop start and end points is not quite so trivial.

Comment: You can use recursion to build the lower half. When the call returns back, print the same line again and it's done.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be of some help:

```
public static void printTree()
    {
        int index = 0;
        for(; index < 5; index++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                if(j <= index)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(j + 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(; index > 0; index--)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                if(j < index)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(j + 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh your solution is even better than mine !
Thank you,

I will learn if there is some others ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The way to program is to break the problem up into smaller chunks and work on one chunk at a time.  Always test each chunk before moving on to the next.

1. Make rows of stars getting longer.  You have done this.
2. Make rows of stars getting shorter.
3. Make rows of digits, increasing.
4. Make rows of digits, decreasing.
5. Append the decreasing digits to the increasing stars.
6. Append the increasing digits to the decreasing stars.
7. Put 5 and 6 together.

Comment: Thank you for these tips, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i = 1; i <=5 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <=i ; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int k = i+1; k <= 5 ; k++) {
            System.out.print(k);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }


    for (int i = 5; i > 0 ; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <=i ; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int k = i+1; k <= 5 ; k++) {
            System.out.print(k);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

---

I don't know if it is the best way, but it seems to work.
I will try another way. Always good to learn.